# Crystal Reports running on a Client Computer (without CRRuntime)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

Good day. I have this desktop application that was installed in our server. Currently, the users are just mapped to the application's EXE. The application is working fine but when I view Crystal Report in the client computer, it gives me this error:

> An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports
>   runtime.
>
> Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficient
>   or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed correctly.
>
> Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports redistributable
>   (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the Crystal Reports
>   runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required.  Please go to
>   http://www.businessobjects.com/support for more information.

I'm using **Visual Studio 2015** and the Crystal Reports for **Visual Studio 2013 (CRforVS_13_0_23)**.

What I've already done:

- Included the required **.dll** for Crystal Reports in the installer.
- Installed the **CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_12** in our server.
- Set the **Platform Target to x86**.

Is there anything else I'm missing here?

Do I need to install the CRRuntime to our client's computer also? Does the processing of the Crystal Reports occurs in the server where the application is hosted?

*(But this option is not applicable to our current set-up, which I know is the not the best way by the way, but I don't have a choice.)*

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal reports provide two separate run-times, one for x86 OSes and another for x64 OSes. Problems like this appear mostly on x64 Windows. Short and sweet way to get things moving is, install both x64 and x86 versions of Crystal Reports run-time on your client systems. I hope it will help you out since it worked for me in the past.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am aware of that. But what I want to know is do I really need to install CRRuntime to our client's PC even though the the application is hosted in the server? Was the CRRuntime supposed to be processed in the server instead since the application is in there?

Comment: CR Runtime is something which is needed by client application to process the reports and show them. I am pretty much sure you are using CR Viewer control also to show reports to clients. Even if report is hosted on server, runtime handles the job to show it to the clients. So yes, runtime is needed for the clients to see reports.